# Android: папки drawable на работают

Tags: android, android-layout, экран, android-drawable

У меня есть 3 папки с разновидностями одного и того же layout-а и 3 соответствующие им папки drawable:

---

*layout-xlarge* и *drawable-xhdpi*

---

*layout-large* и *drawable-hdpi*

---

*layout-normal* и *drawable-mdpi*

---

Почему-то во всех layout-ах используются только картинки из папки drawable-xhdpi, на остальные две папки drawable студия не обращает внимания.

При удалении папки drawable-xhdpi используются только картинки из drawable-hdpi, ну и при удалении drawable-hdpi используется то, что остаётся, drawable-mdpi.

Что  тут не так?

Comment: а какой телефон или эмулятор используется? а то не понятно, как именно **студия** использует? либо переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: @ЕвгенийСуетин, все те телефоны, которые доступны в каждом layout-те. В layout-xlarge -  с плотностью xhdpi, в layout-large - с плотностью hdpi, и в layout-normal - с плотностью mdpi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Модификаторы xlarge и xhdpi никак не связаны между собой (как и large/hdpi, normal/mdpi). Первый параметр отвечает за размер экрана а второй за его плотность (количество точек на дюйм).

Если вы хотите установить соответствие между layout и drawable то сделайте так :

```
layout-xlarge и drawable-xlarge 

layout-large и drawable-large 

layout-normal и drawable-normal
```

Тогда каждому layout будет соответствовать конкретная папка drawable.